# What is a way to automate downloading a picture from a link in Excel/VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, download

So here's the situation: I'm trying to download a number of pictures from an external server onto my local computer.

The Excel file has a link to the picture which will open and download the picture.

What I've tried so far is to convert the hyperlinks into just text (of the picture url) and run the following code.

I'm only basically familiar with VBA, more so with other languages though.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
  Option Explicit

  Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
  Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
  ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
  ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

  Dim Ret As Long

  '~~> This is where the images will be saved. Change as applicable
  Const FolderName As String = "C:\Users\My Name\Downloads\"

  Sub DownloadLinks()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim strPath As String

'~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  For i = 2 To LastRow '<~~ 2 because row 1 has headers
    strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("BP" & i).Value & ".jpg"

    Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("BP" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

    If Ret = 0 Then
        ws.Range("CA" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
    Else
        ws.Range("CA" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
    End If
Next i

  End Sub
```

The column names are irrelevant, but right now, everything comes out as "Unable to download file" or if it is successful, it isn't in the directory I specified.

Is there a better way to code this?

Something about my data maybe?

I'd also like it to save the file name as text in another column if possible, but that isn't necessary.

Right now I just need them to get downloaded.

Comment: Looks like you're using column BP for both the URL and the filename - is that correct?

Comment: I was wondering about that, because the way the links are imported into excel, just the file name is the text for the hyperlink, thought the full address is available in the hyperlink.  This would be perfect as it should name the saved file as the file name and not the entire hyperlink, but it's not doing anything.

Comment: Using the cell value to name the file is fine, but you need to pass the actual URL to the download function, and that's a property of the cell's `Hyperlink` property, and not the cell's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub DownloadLinks()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim strPath As String, strURL As String
Dim c As Range


    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow

        Set c = ws.Range("BP" & i)
        If c.Hyperlinks.Count>0 Then
            strPath = FolderName & c.Value & ".jpg"
            strURL = c.Hyperlinks(1).Address

            Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL, strPath, 0, 0)

            ws.Range("CA" & i).Value = IIf(Ret = 0, _
                                    "File successfully downloaded", _
                                    "Unable to download the file")
        Else
            ws.Range("CA" & i).Value = "No hyperlink!"
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that, but the `strURL = c.Hyperlinks(1).Address` erroed out, "subscript out of range."  Is there a character limit for that? These url's are quite long!

Comment: Try adding `debug.print cell.hyperlinks.count` just above that line and see what the output is.  Are your links actual hyperlinks, or are you using the `HYPERLINK()` formula?

Comment: They're actual hyperlinks.

Comment: `c.Hyperlinks(1).Address` shouldn't error out unless there's no hyperlink in the cell.  See my edited code - try that.

Comment: It works!  Thank Tim, if I had more reputation I'd upvote you.  It took me a couple weeks just to get as far as I had.  Awesome job!