# URLDownloadToFile generates Compile Error: Sub or Function Not Defined

Tags: excel, vba, download

I'm trying to download images from URLs into a folder. I got the below code from a successful answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185853/what-is-a-way-to-automate-downloading-a-picture-from-a-link-in-excel-vba).

```
Sub DownloadLinks()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String, strURL As String
    Dim c As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow

        Set c = ws.Range("BP" & i)
        If c.Hyperlinks.Count>0 Then
            strPath = FolderName & c.Value & ".jpg"
            strURL = c.Hyperlinks(1).Address

            Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL, strPath, 0, 0)

            ws.Range("CA" & i).Value = IIf(Ret = 0, _
                                    "File successfully downloaded", _
                                    "Unable to download the file")
        Else
            ws.Range("CA" & i).Value = "No hyperlink!"
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

When I run the above macro, I get 'Compile Error: Sub or Function Not Defined' in reference to URLDownloadToFile. Elsewhere I have seen URLDownloadToFile defined with this code which turns red as soon as I add it to the macro.

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon"
  Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long,
  ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String,
  ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
```

Adding this to the top of my macro gets me a syntax error on the first line.

Do I need to download a special patch or library to run URLDownloadToFile? I'm running Windows 10, 64-bit. Or is there something wrong with the above macro? Am I not defining URLDownloadToFile properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr _
      ) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As Long _
      ) As Long
#End If

Sub DownloadLinks()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim FolderName as String, strPath As String, strURL As String


    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    FolderName = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\"
    LastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow

        strURL = ws.Range("C" & i).Value
        If len(strURL) Then
            strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("B" & i).Value & ".jpg"
            Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL, strPath, 0, 0)

            ws.Range("D" & i).Value = IIf(Ret = 0, _
                                    "File successfully downloaded", _
                                    "Unable to download the file")
        Else
            ws.Range("D" & i).Value = "No URL!"
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That seems to work, or at least there aren't any errors. Where would I set which folder the images go into? It looks like the image names are column B and URLs column C? Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: It's part of strPath. Your code is using a variable FolderName that you need to define

Comment: I replaced FolderName with "C:\Users\Me\TheFolderName" and the macro ran without errors, but there are no images in the named folder.

Comment: Do the image names go in column B and the image URLs in column C?

Comment: This code is getting the image name from column BP values and the url from column BP hyperlink address. Where are your names and urls?

Comment: I have the urls in column BP, but the macro isn't creating any images in the destination folder. How can the names and the urls both be in column BP?

Comment: I can put the names/urls in any column, just need to know where they go.

Comment: I have edited the code. Put image names in column B and URLs in column C